# DataTables - Hide/Show Columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm trying to Show/Hide columns in DataTables using the Switch Buttons (input checkbox) of Bootstrap.. I have created a functionally *a link* that work to Show/Hide columns, but when i apply the *class* and the *data-column* they don't work with *checkbox*..
The javascript is this:

```js
                $('.toggle-vis').on('click', function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();

                    // Get the column API object
                    var column = table.column($(this).attr('data-column'));

                    // Toggle the visibility
                    column.visible(!column.visible());
                });
```

```html
<a class="toggle-vis" data-column="7">Colina</a>
<input type="checkbox" data-column="0" class="toggle-vis" onchange='OnOff(this, "Carboidrati");' data-label-text="Carboidrati" checked>
```

Comment: Post the code that doesn't work, the rendered page is not too helpful

Comment: You must include your 'default' states for visibility and for the check-box. They act as a ref for any changes of state you create. Normally 'toggle' effects are simple if you follow basic rules.

Comment: The checkbox is visible and the status is checked

Comment: [Here is another solution:](https://jsfiddle.net/nikleshraut/ryat69nc/)  to Show/Hide Datatable's column in a row without knowing column name, Also you can fix any column and make all changes persistent. One more is [colVis](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/column_visibility/columns.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wowser, that was fun to research!!!. The issue is your event handling: in order to "listen" to the switch you need to listen to the [`switchChange.bootstrapSwitch`](http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/events.html) event so altering you code to listen to that rather than `click` should fix your problem:

```
$('.toggle-vis').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function(event, state) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var column = table.column(~~$(this).attr('data-column'));
    column.visible( ! column.visible() );
});
```

Working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/rh6y7va9/), hope that helps.

Comment: Hi, may I ask, I am new and I am very interested with your solution, but I have applied your script but not function. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mastersuse/8og5yqxu/8/)

Comment: @mastersuse: you hadn't included the relevant libraries and your markup was a little confused, that should work: https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/tenL912o/